# Disable chrome/firefox tooltips on required field

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

I am working on angular form validation where user need to input field(which are required)

To work on required field validation I have used angular form validation. using 
`ng-required="ture"`, but unfortunately I am getting tooltip on chrome browser. (see in picture below)

[image]

If I use `novalidate` in input tag. validation is not working,
then how can I display all invalid input field "**required messages**" on submit button click?

[**Fiddler here**](https://jsfiddle.net/venkatrjv/yk4om6un/2/)

Comment: novalidate has to be on form element and not on input tag.. Please look at the answer i posted

Comment: but it just skipping out with out displaying required message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

novalidate will do solve your problem, to show error messages on form submit you can use `form.$submitted` event which trigger during form submit.

For Example in you case

```
 <input type="text" name="taskName" placeholder="Task Name" ng-model="tastName" ng-required="true" />
  <span class="error" ng-show="frm.taskName.$error.required && (frm.taskName.$touched ||  frm.$submitted)">Name is required</span>
```

[**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/yk4om6un/7/)

Comment: but form is first submitting then posting required message.

Comment: please check updated fiddle, all you need to do a check in controller for a valid form, hope it make scene

Comment: thank, is there any way to display border for inputs with are not valid on submit click...

Comment: k i have done it.. no problem . check out my answer :-)

Answer (score 3):

You can add a `novalidate` attribute to the form element to disable browser validation. [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yk4om6un/3/)

Comment: if you know the answer share it here, do not post the links

Comment: @JishnuVS Thank you!

Comment: I would like to have browser validation, but I want it to fail silently. How would that work?

Answer (score 1):

Got the answer using ng-class and form.$submitted (thanks to @Shailendra Sharma answer)

This logic is going display **error message** and **input field decorated with red border** without any chrome tooltip on submit click.

```
 <input type="text" ng-class="{'inputError': (frm.taskName.$error.required && (frm.taskName.$touched ||  frm.$submitted))}" name="taskName" novalidate placeholder="Task Name" ng-model="tastName" ng-required="true" />
        <span class="error" ng-show="frm.taskName.$error.required && (frm.taskName.$touched ||  frm.$submitted)">Name is required</span>
```

[**Fiddler**](https://jsfiddle.net/venkatrjv/yk4om6un/9/)

Answer (score 0):

novalidate is an attribute for forms to let browsers to stop validating

Document here explains it https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form

```
 <form name="frm" ng-submit="add()" novalidate>
      <input type="text" name="taskName" placeholder="Task Name" ng-model="tastName" ng-required="true" />
      <span class="error" ng-show="frm.taskName.$error.required && frm.taskName.$touched">Name is required</span>
      <!--{{ frm.taskName.$error }}-->
      <br />
      <label>estimation time:</label>
      <select ng-model="time" name="time" ng-options="t for t in NOTask" ng-required="true">
        <option value="" selected="selected">Please select</option>
      </select>
      <span class="error" ng-show="frm.time.$error.required && frm.time.$touched">Please select time</span>
      <br /> {{ frm.$valid }}
      <input type="submit" name="name" value="Add" />

    </form>
```

Comment: then how can i display all required field message on submit click

Comment: this will only prevent the default behaviour user based validations will still work fine

Comment: well how can i display all invalid input field "required messages" on submit button click ?

Comment: You need to handle that in ng-submit function

Comment: how can I add it?